# unable to run npm test for angular 2 app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cordova

I'm working with an angular 2 app, and I'm quite new to it, I've setup it with cordova app and running it through npm, app starts without errors and run smoothly, but when I try to run the tests with node (i.e. npm test), it gives following error

```
D:\VisionEngage\VisionEngage>npm test

> VisionEngage@1.0.0 test D:\VisionEngage\VisionEngage
> ng test

As a forewarning, we are moving the CLI npm package to "@angular/cli" with the next release,
which will only support Node 6.9 and greater. This package will be officially deprecated
shortly after.

To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.packageDeprecation=false".

You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the test command.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

I've also tried installing @angular/cli (i.e. npm install @angular/cli) but after that its giving following error

```
D:\VisionEngage\VisionEngage>npm test

> VisionEngage@1.0.0 test D:\VisionEngage\VisionEngage
> ng test

12 07 2017 09:54:39.829:ERROR [config]: Error in config file!
 Error: Version of @angular/compiler-cli needs to be 2.3.1 or greater. Current version is "undefined".
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\VisionEngage\VisionEngage\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js:27:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\VisionEngage\VisionEngage\node_modules\angular-cli\models\webpack-configs\test.js:5:17)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

As it said version of @angular/compiler-cli needs to be 2.3.1 or greater for this operation to run then I tried to install the same version through npm (i.e. npm install @angular/compiler-cli@2.3.1) but it didn't succeed as it have some unmet dependencies , error for this operation is following

```
D:\VisionEngage\VisionEngage>npm install @angular/compiler-cli@2.3.1
VisionEngage@1.0.0 D:\VisionEngage\VisionEngage
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@2.2.1 invalid
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler-cli@2.3.1 invalid
| `-- @angular/tsc-wrapped@0.5.0
|   `-- tsickle@0.2.6
|     +-- source-map@0.5.6
|     `-- source-map-support@0.4.15
|       `-- source-map@0.5.6
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.2.1 invalid
```

I've tried to resolve this by installing/updating all these dependencies but couldn't get it resolved. May be I'
m doing something wrong or somethings is missing, any help would be apprciated.

```
Environment: Windows 10 (64 bit)
Node version : 6.11.0
Npm version:  3.10.10
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed Node and npm versions and it worked for me, running node 5.9.1 and npm 3.8.6 version.